# Logging aspect for exceptions with JMS retry mechansim

Tags: java, spring, logging, jms, activemq-classic

In our project we use Activemq (jms template) - to publish many events from one webapp to another.
we use logging aspect (spring aop) as well - mainly we log errors and entering\quitting methods.

Now, sometimes we face racing conditions on the flow of the systems. i.e. an entity is being created on one web app, an event is fired to notify another webapp, but the handling of the other webapp requires a different event to be handled first, so if such scenario happens, the handling fails (for example, an id is missing ) and immediately retried (jms re-delivery), on the 2nd time of the retry its usually works (never more then 3 retries are required).

So basically, we have exceptions as part of our day to day flow, but:

our log files are huge and messy because of the exceptions thrown by such scenarios, any idea how can we not log the first few retries exceptions and only on a later exception we will log? Maybe another approach you can recommend?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JMSXDeliveryCount` property of `Message` to get the redelivery count. See http://activemq.apache.org/activemq-message-properties.html